# Recoding turns everything into the same value in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, recode

I'm practicing R and I created a new column that had continuous numbers in them called ROI, and wanted to recode the number values into string values in R like this:

```
df = mutate(diabetes_df, ROI = ifelse(ROI < 18.5, 'Under', ROI))
df = mutate(diabetes_df, ROI = ifelse(ROI >= 18.5 & ROI <= 25, 'average', ROI))

diabetes_df = mutate(diabetes_df, ROI = ifelse(ROI > 25 & BMI <= 30, 'above average', ROI))
```

This works normally and it displays these words wherever the condition is met, however when i put the last `ifelse` statement :

```
df = mutate(diabetes_df, ROI = ifelse(ROI > 30, 'OVER', ROI))
```

It turns every value in the new column I made into the `OVER` value. I was wondering if anyone knew how to make it so that it would only say `OVER` for where the condition is met?

Comment: @akrun ROI is numeric, i apologize for not stating that earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can replicate the problem with the `mtcars` data frame. The following code on the third `mutate()` statement results in all rows getting the `wt` value set to `High` because after the first `mutate()`, the `wt` column is a vector of character values.

```
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- mutate(mtcars,wt = ifelse(wt < 2.6,"Low", wt))
# at this point, wt is character
str(mtcars$wt)


> str(mtcars$wt)
 chr [1:32] "2.62" "2.875" "Low" "3.215" "3.44" "3.46" "3.57" "3.19" "3.15" ...
```

By the third `mutate()` all rows meet the condition of TRUE for the `if_else()` based on a character string comparison where the string values of `Low` and `Medium` are greater than the number 3.61.

```
mtcars <- mutate(mtcars, wt = ifelse( 2.6 <= wt & wt <= 3.61,"Medium",wt))
mtcars <- mutate(mtcars, wt = ifelse( wt > 3.61,"High",wt))
```

...and the output:

```
> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 High 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 High 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 High 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 High 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 High 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 High 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

We can prevent this behavior by using `case_when()`, which makes all of the comparisons to the numeric version of `wt` in a single pass of the data.

```
# use case_when()
data(mtcars)
mtcars %>% mutate(wt = case_when(
     wt < 2.6 ~ "Low",
     wt >= 2.6 & wt <= 3.61 ~ "Medium",
     wt > 3.61 ~ "High"
)) %>% head(.)
```

...and the output:

```
head(.)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat     wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 Medium 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 Medium 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85    Low 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 Medium 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 Medium 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 Medium 20.22  1  0    3    1
>
```

From the comments to this answer, it wasn't clear to the OP how to save the changed column to the existing data frame. The following code snippet addresses that question.

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars %>% mutate(wt = case_when(
     wt < 2.6 ~ "Low",
     wt >= 2.6 & wt <= 3.61 ~ "Medium",
     wt > 3.61 ~ "High"
)) -> mtcars
```

Comment: what if you don't want to make a new column as you already have a column that existed? @Len Greski

Comment: In the `mtcars` data frame, `wt` is an existing, numeric column.

Comment: my bad i mean to say how would you add that column into a existing dataset? it seems that that it shows in the console, but not in the actual dataset

Answer (score 2):

- If ROI is a numeric column, the issue is that you are overwriting a numeric column with text values.
- If ROI is not a numeric column, then inequality comparison on text strings works different from how you have assumed.

Note that all you commands take the form: `df = mutate(df, ROI = ifelse(ROI <condition>, 'label', ROI)`. This means you are overwriting the original ROI values, and the replaced values will we used for subsequent comparisons.

Suppose df had only row with `ROI = 10` then:

```r
# df:
# ROI = 10

df2 = mutate(df, ROI = ifelse(ROI < 18.5, 'Under', ROI))
# compares 10 < 18.5
# replaces 10 with 'Under'

# df2:
# ROI = 'Under'

df3 = mutate(df2, ROI = ifelse(ROI > 30, 'OVER', ROI))
# compares 'Under' > 30
# After standardizing formats, compares 'Under' > '30' (conversion to string)
# replaces 'Under' with 'OVER'
```

Two possible solutions:

1. write to a different column, this is good practice

```r
df %>%
  mutate(ROI_label = NA) %>%
  mutate(ROI_label = ifelse(ROI < 18.5, 'Under', ROI_label)) %>%
  mutate(ROI_label = ifelse(ROI >= 18.5 & ROI <= 25, 'average', ROI_label)) %>%
  mutate(ROI_label = ifelse(ROI > 25 & BMI <= 30, 'above average', ROI_label)) %>%
  mutate(ROI_label = ifelse(ROI > 30, 'OVER', ROI_label))
```

2. use `case_when`, this is also good practice

```r
df %>%
  mutate(ROI = case_when(ROI < 18.5 ~ 'Under',
                         ROI >= 18.5 & ROI <= 25 ~ 'average',
                         ROI > 25 & BMI <= 30 ~ 'above average',
                         ROI > 30 ~ 'OVER'))
```

Even better, write to a different column and use `case_when`.

Comment: ROI is a numeric value, sorry for not stating that

Comment: May be you can make it simpler with `cut` or `findInterval`

Comment: do you know how to add that column into a existing dataset? it seems when i run this code it creates the columns in the console but not in the actual dataset

Comment: You need to assign the output: `df <- df %>% mutate(...`